# How does the command "cd WSMan:\localhost\shell" work? How can I reproduce it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-provider, winrm

I am able to use Powershell to configure WinRM using a special "cd" command.  Can anyone explain how it works and how I can implement that type of plug in for my own app?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at is a PowerShell Provider.  You can implement providers to expose data or configuration information as a file system.

This link should get your started, but know that providers are more difficult to implement than cmdlets.

[Writing a Windows PowerShell Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee126192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)